# background color not showing in footer

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I remade a page using Bootstrap 4 and cannot seem to figure out why the footer background color is not showing. [The page is up here](http://driftwoodrentals.com)

```css
.footer {
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: visible;
  color: #004289;
  font-weight: bold;
  height: 2rem;
  background-color: #CFFEEE;
}
```

```html
<footer class="footer">
<div class="container">
<div class="text-center">Copyright &copy; <script>document.write(new Date().getFullYear());</script> The Driftwood</div>
</div>
</footer>
```

I think my brain is exploding over something that should be so simple. Thanks
edit: it appears how I would like in the Run Code Snippet manager below. If you need more code just ask, or view the live page. 
this is what I see 
[image]

in the head section I link to the BS css and to my custom css like this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="dist/css/custom-bs4.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: your web doesnt detect this .footer you had made in css.. Please advise in which file it have

Comment: @mlegg the problem is the background-color of the div class='container' that your footer div contains. Add a class to that div with different background colour and you'll see the difference.

Answer (score 5):

Your `.container` white background is overriding it, since it is a more specific selector than `.footer`.

To override you can do:

```
.footer .container {
  background-color: #CFFEEE;
}
```

Comment: @mlegg this answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your page [Your page link](http://driftwoodrentals.com/index-test.html) has the proper footer background in desktop but in mobile it is white. The reason behind it is , you have defined

```
@media (min-width: 767px)
custom-bs4.css:395
.footer .container {
    background-color: #CFFEEE;
}
```

So when it comes to mobile size the width get reduce from 767px. SO your this condition does not get satisfied. Instead,it is applying the below style:

```
.container {
     background-color: #fff; 
}
```

So only on your mobile background color is white.

So try using one more `@media` for mobile screen what color you want for footer or remove the specification for  `@media` `min-width` for the footer.
Also you can give a try :

```
.footer .container {
  background-color: #CFFEEE;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To remove the background of .container:

```
.container {
    background: none;
}
```

You can also define it as standard:

```
* {
    background: none;
}
```

I think this is a better option than giving the .container the same background, cause this can help you fix a lot of other problems

Answer (score 0):

In the link to the website it seems like you have a problem with the css:

```
span.navbar-toggler-icon {
        background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,%3Csvg viewBox='0 0 32 32' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%3E%3Cpath stroke='rgba(0,51,102)' stroke-width='3' stroke-linecap='round' stroke-miterlimit='10' d='M4 8h24M4 16h24M4 24h24'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");

.navbar .navbar-toggler:hover span.icon-bar {
  background: #004289;
}
```

If you note, the `span.navbar-toggler-icon` has an open `{` but not a closing one. Starting from there - the entire css file is not valid (syntax error since you didn't close that selector).

You can use the following css validator to check your css:
https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/validator?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdriftwoodrentals.com%2Fdist%2Fcss%2Fcustom-bs4.css&profile=css3&usermedium=all&warning=1&vextwarning=&lang=en

Answer (score 0):

I could see background #fff for your innercontainer .container element. that overlaps your footer background color.

```
.container {
     background-color: #fff;
}
```

line no 10 in custom-bs4.css

Answer (score 0):

You may have to reload your css page...  It may have been cached for you ;)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone! I didn't think of adding `.footer .container {
  background-color: #CFFEEE;
}`

It works when the page is full screen but when it's minimized narrower, like mobile, the footer area goes back to white again with the navy text. How can I fix that?